# Messy output of tcPDF

Tags: php, phpexcel, tcpdf

I am trying to read a .xlsx template, change some of its content and save it to a pdf file. For that, I use PHPExcel and tcPDF as PDF renderer. The problem is, I can't quite get the output right. Here is the code that I use:

```
include_once "../class/PHPExcel.php";
include_once "../class/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
include_once "../class/PHPExcel/Cell.php";
include_once "../class/PHPExcel/Worksheet/MemoryDrawing.php";
include_once "../class/PHPExcel/Settings.php";

$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
$libraryPath = "../class/tcpdf_6_2_13/tcpdf_isee";
PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName, $libraryPath);

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$fileTemplate = $reader->load("1 Lambung (A Dokumentasi dan gambar rencana).xlsx");
$fileTemplate->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$fileTemplate->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridlines(false);
$fileTemplate->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow(6, 24, "N");
$fileTemplate->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow(6, 28, "N");

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($fileTemplate, 'pdf');
$writer->save("1 Lambung (A Dokumentasi dan gambar rencana)ed.pdf");
```

I also made some change in the `PHPExcel_Writer_PDF_tcPDF` as follows (I only add one line to set cell height ratio, changing the unit to inch and delete the 72 dpi conversion):

```
//  Create PDF
    $pdf = new TCPDF($orientation, 'in', $paperSize);
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);
    //    Set margins, converting inches to points (using 72 dpi)
    $pdf->SetMargins($printMargins->getLeft(), $printMargins->getTop(), $printMargins->getRight());
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $printMargins->getBottom());
    $pdf->setCellHeightRatio(0.8);
```

This is the screenshot of the template:

[Excel Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiKl2.jpg)

And these are the pdf output:

[PDF Output page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybvUO.jpg)

Sorry for the inconvenience, I am still unable to embed image due to insufficient reputation.

For a summary, here's the problem in the output:

- There is a big spacing between lines. I tried to fix it by reducing cell height ratio using `setCellHeightRatio` method. It works for rows which have empty rows between them, but for rows that is next to each other, the content will overlap. As a last resort I will try to modify the template, but right now I still think the problem lies in my code
- The page margin is bigger than what is set in the original template
- The line width of the table border is not the same as the original template. I tried to set the line width using `setLineWidth` but there is no effect
- Some content of the cell is pushed to the next line

Could anyone please help me on this?